# Cache simulation in gem5

Tags: caching, gem5

Happy new year to everyone!
I want to know how to change caches' parameters in gem5. I usually use se.py configuration script for my simulations. Can I change caches's latencies in se.py? Is there an option for that?

Comment: Which cache model are you using: Classic or Ruby?

Comment: In any case, configs/Options.py does not list any latency-related option, so if you want to add new command line options you will likely need to add your own. This will require modifications to both configs/Options.py (to add the new option) and configs/CacheConfig.py to translate the new option into a recognizable parameter for the cache object. Commit https://gem5-review.googlesource.com/c/public/gem5/+/36776 may help you understand. The list of valid parameters (which include latencies) is found (for Classic) in src/mem/cache/Cache.py

Comment: However, we strongly recommend creating your own configuration script (http://learning.gem5.org/book/part1/simple_config.html), and then assigning the default values there.

Comment: @DanielCarvalho it might be possible to set them with `fs.py --param` at least in classic BTW for quick tests.

Comment: I am aware of that, but I'd rather recommend users to be fully aware of what they are doing before going for the "hacks". Thanks anyway, @Ciro :)